# What is the image of $f:A\to B\times C\cup\{\emptyset\}$?

Tags: notation

Let $f:A\to B\times C\cup\{\emptyset\}$ be any function. My question is simple. **Given some $a\in A$, is this function $f:A\to B\times C\cup\{\emptyset\}$ returning either a pair $(a,b)\in A\times B$ or the empty set; or is this function returning a pair $(a,b)\in A\times B\cup\{\emptyset\}$, where $b$ could be the empty set?**

Comment: It is returning a pair $(b,c) \in B \times C$ or the empty set.

Comment: **Thank you**. Would you post it as an answer, along with some explanation of your liking?

Comment: I think it's ambiguous, it depends on whether it's $(B\times C)\cup \{\emptyset\}$ or $B\times (C\cup\{\emptyset\})$.

Comment: So, to avoid confusion you'd write $(B\times C)\cup\{\emptyset\}$ or $B\times (C\cup\{\emptyset\}$ depending on what I want?

Comment: @Héctor Yes, that would be reasonable. If you’re reading this somewhere, you might be able to figure out what the author means from the context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the function is written as $f: A \to B \times C \cup \{\emptyset\}$ which means that the range of values is $B \times C \cup \{\emptyset\}$ (because that is the set "right of the arrow"). Now this set of possible values is a union of two sets meaning that the output $f(a)$ for some $a$ is in either one of those two sets (normally it could also be an element of both of the sets in the union, but here the two sets $B \times C$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ are disjoint). Therefore $f(a)$ is going to give you either a pair $(b,c) \in B \times C$ or a value in the set $\{\emptyset\}$ which can only be $f(a) = \emptyset$.